# Can OID technology return an X, Y coordinate?

Tags: identification, optical

We are working with a overseas vendor that is using [SONIX OID technology](http://www.sonix.com.tw/category-en-956?tabIndex=list).
(according to our vendor we are using OID v2)

We are using OID technology from them. A smartpen with OID technology is able to optically recognize small patterns printed on paper. It is able to discern if you touch certain areas (you have to define them) on the printed media.

I know that we can define areas on printed media and assign certain IDs.  Imagine you have picture of a piano with 88 keys, a drum, a guitar...  You can assign different parts of the band different IDs.  For example you define the drum as a region and that gets ID:1 and it plays drumsound. You define the guitar as another region and that gets ID:2 and it plays guitarsound, etc.

However, I'm trying to see if OID technology can also give you back an X, Y coordinate when the pen touches the paper.

The reason why I want to do this for example is I want to map the keys of the piano to different pitches.  Instead of defining 88 regions, I just want to check what the X,Y is and I can determine via math which key they touched.

I'm trying to search on their website to see whether OID can return X, Y.

Does anyone on this list have experience with OID and specifically with SONIX?
If so, can you help me out here?

Thank you.

Comment: '*If anyone is interested search for "sonix technology co" ...*'. Um, if you're interested in responses maybe you would provide the link? Add one for OID too and explain the acronym. (All info in the question, please, rather than scattered through the comments.)

Comment: Just added the link.

Comment: have you asked the vendor?

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be done by assigning the sound folder as per your requirement to the corresponding marked area index code number , this produces the required audio sound

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need more details in your answer, or it will be flagged as LQ.